# When getting a list of files to process, should I store them to a list of string, or a list of Stream?

Tags: c#, .net

for a list of files, coming from a list like from a file dialog is it better to store the list as a list of strings or should I convert each file to opened Streams stored in a List?

For example

```
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        List<FileStream> fileStreams = new List<FileStream>();

        foreach (Stream f in fileStreams)
        {
            //process stream
        }

        **VS**

        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            //open filestream
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Open);

            //process
        }
```

Comment: Streams will take more memory than strings, so I would take a simple string.

Comment: So then store them as strings and open them as Streams as needed one by one?

Comment: Yeah, I am writing a little memory test

Comment: It's not really about memory.  One stream can usually keep a hard drive 100% busy, so unless you're switching between streams for some reason (e.g. copying operations), having more than one stream open simultaneously seldom makes sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah you're right, that is another big problem. Actually I know situations, where you have more than one stream open, but all of them are in `Parallel.ForEach` situations.

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @gnat I added an example if that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep them as `string` as long a possible.

A stream is bound to external resources (hidden buffers, read ahead cache,...) and it is a good idea to minimized the time those are bound to your objects.

Some systems have a hard limit of how many files are open as well so if you open all streams at once it may happen that some streams don't open.